# How to programmatically align a button in iOS Applications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How will I be able to **align** a normal **UIButton** eg. on the top, bottom or middle programmatically?

Comment: you can align button by setting its freame.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set the center of button to place it accordingly

```
yourButton.center = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);// for topleft

yourButton.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 240.0);// for center

yourButton.center = CGPointMake(320.0, 480.0);// for bottomright
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't compensate for the size of the button, however. For example, on the first line, you button will be partially out of view.

Comment: actually the guy wants to align the button(top, bottom or middle) and not setting the frame, so accordingly I gave my answer

Comment: Are 320 and 480 also valid metrics for IPhone 5 or 5S?

Comment: You could also do this: buttonPlayQuiz.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2 + 50). The '+50' is optional and will position the button 50px further down from the center y axis. Just remove the '+50' if you want the button in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 54):

You have to set `UIButton` frame your self.

**Horizontally Alignment**

```
float X_Co = (self.view.frame.size.width - yourButtonWidth)/2;
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, yourYposition, yourButtonWidth, yourButtonheight)];
```

**Vertically  Align**

```
float Y_Co = (self.view.frame.size.height - yourButtonheight)/2;
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(yourXposition, Y_Co, yourButtonWidth, yourButtonheight)];
```

**TOP LEFT**

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, yourButtonWidth, yourButtonheight)];
```

**TOP RIGHT**

```
float X_Co = self.view.frame.size.width - yourButtonWidth;
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, 0.0, yourButtonWidth, yourButtonheight)];
```

**BOTTOM LEFT**

```
float Y_Co = self.view.frame.size.height - yourButtonheight;
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, Y_Co, yourButtonWidth, yourButtonheight)];
```

**BOTTOM RIGHT**

```
float X_Co = self.view.frame.size.width - yourButtonWidth;
float Y_Co = self.view.frame.size.height - yourButtonheight;
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, Y_Co, yourButtonWidth, yourButtonheight)];
```

**Center Of self.view**

```
button.center = self.view.center;
OR
float X_Co = (self.view.frame.size.width - yourButtonWidth)/2;
float Y_Co = (self.view.frame.size.height - yourButtonheight)/2;
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, Y_Co, yourButtonWidth, yourButtonheight)];
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, you might encounter graphic issues when you center a frame when it's hight or width is an uneven value like 15 pixels. The frame might start at some half pixel, blurring the view. To fix this, one solution could be to correct the frame by using `button.frame = CGRectIntegral( button.frame );` after the center is set.

Comment: But X_Co and Y_Co are float value.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers! I wish I could accept all of them! I am a newbie and don't know what numbers or values I would have to put in to allign it somewhere. Is there any guide to understand to understand screen height width etc values?

Comment: Just plus and minus nothing else. See my answer and try to understand i have written logics :) All the best !

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs - Thanks ! Would you plz tell me that is it wrong with float variables ? in case of 15 will not it take 7.5 ?

Comment: It will take 7.5, but text and images will look "blurry", because they start at a half pixel. To fix this, the method `CGRectIntegral();` can be used to make "whole" values, e.g. 7.5 will become 7.0. You can test the blurry images yourself when you create a button with e.g. width 73 and height 25 and use the `center` method to align it.

Comment: button.center = self.view.center works if I remain in one mode (portrait vs landscape).  It does not work if I move the device from portrait to landscape mode.  How do I make sure button remains centered as I switch between these modes?

Comment: @SmartHome You need to set it again in orientation did change method. You can use animation so that it looks good while changing the position.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to set the position of a subview is manually. You can set the frame, like this, for example:

[image]

Or change the origin, like this, for example:

`view.frame.origin.x = INT_VALUE;`

The only way to get some kind of alignment is to do math with `self.view.frame`. If you want to align an object horizontally with the middle of the screen, use this:

`view.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width / 2`

If you want to align something to the top with a margin of 44 pixels, use this:

`view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y = (view.frame.size.height / 2) + 44;`

Etc.

Comment: I like the absoluteness with which you answered. "The only way" xD

Answer (score 3):

You should set its frame.

Something like

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 120, 35, 10)];
```

or

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(320, 120, 35, 10);
```

Keep in mind that the first couple of values are respectively the width and the height (position in X and Y) of the view and the second couple of values are the width and the height of the button itself.

So, if you want a button on top, you should type

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 10);
```

Middle

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 35, 10);
```

Bottom

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(320, 480, 35, 10);
```

Comment: I'l have to wait 8 minutes to accept this answer :P StackOverFlow wont let me accept answers so fast :) Nevertheless I will surely accept it after the long 8 min wait :)

Comment: No problems, the important is that you got how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

great tip of the @TheTiger! 
I put this logic in a swift class:

https://github.com/iurims/iSLibs/blob/master/ISPositionCalculator.swift

Comment: If you include a code snippet inline with your answer, it remains useful even if that GitHub repo goes away (or becomes private, or the file names change, or...)